# Tkinter - Button Image Transparent Background

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label, transparency

I have worked out how to have an image for a button, thats positioned on top of a label (*I think I maybe doing it the long-winded way because I can't install PIL on my Mac for some reason*). Anyhow, it works as it should to a certain degree - the problem I have is it's adding white space either side, and then the image itself is not displaying its transparent background.

[image]

The code I am using is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import Image

root = Tk()


#Removes the title bar and places over mac top bar
root.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle", "style", root._w, "plain", "none")
# Makes the app full screen
#root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(480, 320))
#root.attributes('-topmost', True)

def quitApp():
    # mlabel = Label (root, text = 'Close').pack()
    root.destroy()


background_img = PhotoImage(file="images/bg.gif")
scanBtn_img = PhotoImage(file="images/scanBtn.gif")

background = Label(root,
                   compound = CENTER,
                   quitButton = Button(image=scanBtn_img, command = quitApp).pack(),
                   image = background_img).pack(side="right")

background.image = background_img # keep a reference!


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: are you sure you are on python 2.7 because you are importing tkinter in lowercase as python 3.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand tkinter natively supports transparency on images like GIF.

I chopped up your code a little but it does work for me. Maybe there is a problem with how you have set up your code. Your label also has a button in it. I don't think you need to have both. You can just created the button where you want it.

Just for reference I created a Label and a Button packed on different sides with a black background to show the transparency of the image.

Here is the code I used to test a `gif` I have that has transparency. I tested this on both python 3.6 and 2.7 just in case.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def quitApp():
    root.destroy()

background_img = PhotoImage(file="Colors/sa.gif")
scanBtn_img = PhotoImage(file="Colors/sa.gif")

background = Label(root,bg='black', image = background_img).pack(side = RIGHT)               
quitButton = Button(bg='black', image=scanBtn_img, command = quitApp).pack(side = LEFT)
backgroundimage = background_img # keep a reference!

root.mainloop()
```

Update: I used the gif you link in the comment

Here is the result.

[image]

Update:

After doing some more digging I found what might work for Mac OS:

I don't have a Mac to test on right now so let me know if this works for you:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Hide the root window drag bar and close button
root.overrideredirect(True)
# Make the root window always on top
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
# Make the window content area transparent
root.wm_attributes("-transparent", True)
# Set the root window background color to a transparent color
root.config(bg='systemTransparent')

def quitApp():
    root.destroy()

background_img = PhotoImage(file="Colors/1.gif")
scanBtn_img = PhotoImage(file="Colors/1.gif")


background = Label(root,bg='black', image = background_img)
background.pack(side = RIGHT)
background.config(bg='systemTransparent')
quitButton = Button(bg='black', image=scanBtn_img, command = quitApp)
quitButton.pack(side = LEFT)
quitButton.config(bg='systemTransparent')
backgroundimage = background_img # keep a reference!

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That must be a mac thing. I will have to look into it a little more.

Comment: Ahh that may explain it, I am using this image https://image.prntscr.com/image/d036fce797e94291bd38040bd7eb4bd0.gif

Comment: Ah. It would help if your `gif` was actually transparent XD

Comment: it isn't isn't it? for me it is? I just tried with this transparent gif https://i.giphy.com/yqMtk0TfjRa5W.gif and it was the same - maybe its a mistake by me?

Comment: I think it must be a Mac issue because I see something different :(

Comment: I did find something that looks promising for mac. I am unable to test it but it should work. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for putting in effort - but still same for me :(

Comment: That's very interesting. Well when I get home I might have to install a virtual hackintosh to play around with so I have something to test mac issues on. I will update my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: @Mike-SMT have you eventually work something out for mac?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque No I have not found a solution for MAC. I know MAC has many issue related to Tkinter GUI. I think a MAC person who spend more time on mac than I have who works with tkinter might be able to help but I have yet to find a solution.