# tkinter making background image as semi-transparent under all widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

First image:

[image]

Second image:

[image]

The first image shows what I'm getting at this moment.

But I just want to make it as the 2nd image which is looking transparent for all widgets. Apparently `tkinter` widgets does not support transparency. How can I make my GUI like second image?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, use the StackOverflow to search and if you don't find anything, then you write your question.

Here are some related questions/answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857757/transparent-backgrounds-on-buttons-in-tkinter

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331618/tkinter-button-image-transparent-background

Comment: Like you said, tkinter doesn't support transparency, except on the whole window on some platforms.

Comment: I already saw the related questions, it doesnt work and not a solution. Thats why I posted this question.

Comment: please paste your code which  you had already tried .

Answer (score 1):

I know question is asked long ago, but I(and probably still many beginners like myself) was bothered with same thing and I came up with some kind of solution. 
I've just cut part of background of exact place where button is placed with exact measurements and I achieved something similar to transparency by placing that cropped image as background of a button, label....

Not a "coded" solution but worked for me.