# Making a transparent menu button image

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I am getting some issues making a menubutton with a transparent image. I have used transparent images before for buttons and had no problem removing the background. But, when creating a Menubutton, I can't seem to make the image transparent.

Using this code, I am able to make a normal button, using an image that has a transparent background (such as a circle) and I can remove the default coloured button background:

```
button = tk.Button(self, compound = tk.TOP, borderwidth = 0, image = photo, text="some text", command = lambda: somemethod())
```

I try to replicate this on a menubutton using the following code:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("test.TButton", borderwidth = 0)

self.mb = ttk.Menubutton(self, text = "Menu", style = "test.TButton", image = photo)
```

But I am unable to get rid of the default button background, can anyone help me achieve this?

In case it isn't clear, my goal is to have a menubutton using an image without a background rather than text, if there is a better method for doing this, I would be grateful if someone would let me know.

To be clear, my problem is specifically with ttk Menubuttons, not regular tk buttons.

Also, in case it matters at all, i am using Pillow for image processing and using PNG files.

Here is a minimal code of the issue:

```
""" os imports """
import os

""" tkinter imports """
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

""" pillow imports """
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        home_path = os.path.normpath("Java.png")
        self.home_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(home_path))

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("test.TButton", borderwidth = 0, compound = tk.TOP)

        self.mb = ttk.Menubutton(parent, text = "Menu", style = "test.TButton", image = self.home_icon)
        self.mb.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)

        button = tk.Button(parent, compound = tk.TOP, borderwidth = 0, image = self.home_icon, text="test", command = lambda: test()).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)

    def test(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    """ change aspect ratio of the program """
    sizex = 1280
    sizey = 720
    posx  = 0
    posy  = 0
    root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

    main = MainView(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

link to image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWWS3.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more code—preferably an [mcve]. `ttk.Menubutton`s are always used in combination with a `tkinter.Menu` widget.

Comment: That is the whole code, except for the grid/pack/place. The button and image displays for me but is not transparent as i would like it to be. I didnt bother to write any further code for it as it is not currently displaying as i would like. the tkinter.Menu is not required for the image to display correctly.

Comment: Your code doesn't show what `self` is in the `ttk.Menubutton(self, ...)` call. Also, the image type matters...there are different "flavors" of PNG format images. Please add a link to the image file to your question, as well as enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ive added a minimal example and a link to the image, you should be able to see the side by side difference between the button and menubutton

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331618/tkinter-button-image-transparent-background can be useful in that case.

Comment: im not sure how that answer is supposed to be helpful. The issue i am having seems to be specifically with either using a Menubutton or the way i am using the style class, which i dont think i am doing wrong. Plus, the image that i have used is definitely transparent and is supported as it is shown as transparent on the button in my example but not the Menubutton.
If there is a way to display a menu using a regular button, that would be useful and i could probably just use that if the Menubutton is being difficult.

Comment: According to this (somewhat dated) [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Menubutton.html), a `ttk.Menubutton` _doesn't_ support the `buttonbackground` option that `Tkinter Menubutton`s do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're try to do, but this [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Menubutton.html) says:

> A `Menubutton` widget is the part of a drop-down menu that is always visible. It is ***always*** used in combination with a `Menu` widget that controls what appears when the user clicks on the `Menubutton`.

(Emphasis mine)

So the following does that and appears to be able to create a `ttk.Menubutton` with a transparent background as far as I can tell.

```
import os

""" tkinter imports """
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

""" pillow imports """
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        home_path = os.path.normpath("Java.png")
        self.home_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(home_path))

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("test.TButton", borderwidth=0, compound=tk.TOP)

        self.mb = ttk.Menubutton(parent, text="Menu", style="test.TButton",
                                 image=self.home_icon)
        self.mb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W)

        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.mb, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_command(label='Test', command=lambda: self.test)

        self.mb['menu'] = self.menu

#        button = tk.Button(parent, compound=tk.TOP, borderwidth=0, image=self.home_icon,
#                           text="test", command=lambda: self.test)
#        button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W)

    def test(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    """ change aspect ratio of the program """
    sizex = 800
    sizey = 600
    posx  = 50
    posy  = 50
    root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

    main = MainView(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Result displayed:

[image: screenshot showing menubutton]

Comment: I'm aware that the Menubutton is always used with a Menu widget, i just did not see the need to write that part before i could confirm that the Menubutton was visually acceptable, it was not necessary for the Menubutton to display. But regardless, the button is not transparent. I added a label to the code situated behind the button, expanded and filled it, gave it a black background. If the button was transparent, i should only see the image and the black background, here is the result: https://gyazo.com/1b66d88826930069453cf3d87d102b2c
The button still has its grey background.

Comment: What i am trying to do is have a button that i can use to access a menu, with an image like the Hamburger button. But, i dont want the background of the button to be visible, just the image.